# Symfony EasyAdmin value field considered null (and violate not null constraint)

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I have an EasyAdmin panel to add products in database.

My ProductCrudController looks like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;






use App\Entity\Product;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\SlugField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\ImageField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\MoneyField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextareaField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\AssociationField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\BooleanField;

class ProductCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Product::class;
    }


    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        return [
            TextField::new('name'),
            SlugField::new('slug')->setTargetFieldName('name'),
            ImageField::new('Illustration')
                ->setBasePath('images')
                ->setUploadDir('public/assets/images')
                ->setUploadedFileNamePattern('[randomhash].[extension]')
                ->setRequired('false'),
            TextField::new('subtitle'),
            TextareaField::new('description'),
            BooleanField::new('isBest'),
            MoneyField::new('price')->setCurrency('EUR'),
            AssociationField::new('category')

        ];
    }
}
```

When I try to add a product, the values of all fields are saved, except for the "description" field.

I get the following error :

*An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23502]: Not null violation: 7 ERROR: null value in column "description" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL: Failing row contains (14, 5, TestName, testname, d4090e87b44852e9f570057216d86a7cc2e10164.jpg, testSubtitle, null, 3200, f).*

I can't understand why the other fields are working and "description" does not.

Comment: Try to clean the cache,add required to field 
`TextareaField::new('description')->setRequired(true),` or change field type to `TextField::new('description')` if the problem persists.